# Turning CAPSLOCK into a dead key in linux?

Tags: linux, capslock, dead-keys

I'm running Linux (`Ubuntu 20.04`) with the `XFCE4` window manager. I know some ways to remap the CAPSLOCK key to either be a no-op or to emulate a different key. However, I'm wondering if there is a way to map CAPSLOCK as a dead key?

In other words, I'd like to do things like the following ...

```
CAPSLOCK + a  =>  á
CAPSLOCK + n  =>  ñ
... etc. ...
```

I know about `~/.XCompose`, but I haven't been able to find any docs about how to map CAPSLOCK as a dead key, or even if that's possible.

Thank you in advance for any thoughts and suggestions.

**PS**: Note that the term "dead key" has a special meaning. It does ***not*** mean "a key that is mapped to do nothing" (and I even specified above that I already know how to make CAPSLOCK be a no-op, and that is ***not*** what I'm asking about here). What follows is a more complete definition of "dead key", as I am using the term here.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_key

Comment: [Double posting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/713536/turning-capslock-into-a-dead-key) is not recommended.

Comment: I have now deleted the post in the other forum. It was sitting there unanswered for 2 days, and I had forgotten to delete it when posting here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm doing something similar, albeit not with XFace, and not quite as simplistic as your mappings.

I for instance want to be able to produce àáâäå as well, so I use a cadence of keys ...

Setting it up like so:

```
/usr/bin/setxkbmap -model pc105 -layout us -variant altgr-intl -option nodeadkeys,compose:caps
```

That command resides in my `~/.fluxbox/startup`

This then allows me to e.g. create an á with the following sequence of Keys:

<kbd>Caps</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd>

Other examples:  ñ

<kbd>Caps</kbd>+<kbd>~</kbd> <kbd>n</kbd>

Comment: Aha! That works! Thank you very much.
Well, actually, it doesn't work in xterm windows, but it does indeed work in other apps such as browsers, etc.
I wonder if there's something special I have to do in order to get it to work in xterm.
Oh, and it works in emacs, also.

Comment: That's odd ... what's your locale, how's your xterm set-up? I'm using `en_US.UTF-8` and it works in all apps, including xterm and rxvt-unicode ...

Comment: Yes, my locale is also `en_US.UTF-8`.  And I usually use rxvt-unicode. I'll investigate further

Comment: Perhaps my xterm issue is due to the following (???) ... `When IM framework such as ibus is installed and activated, pure X applications (X clients which was designed to get keyboard inputs from X server through X connection with XIM) protocol) such as xterm and rxvt-unicode don't talk to the X server directly for keyboard inputs. The IM framework such as ibus handles actual keyboard inputs and pass processed data to X clients using XIM protocol from its daemon such as ibus-daemon, instead. `

Comment: I'm also using Ubuntu 20.04, rxvt is compiled w/ XIM support, but it's still just working for me .... maybe fluxbox does something differently to xface?

Comment: I have accepted this as a good answer. However, I have a further question:
Is there a way to map CapsLock to ***always*** turn a following vowel into the vowel with an acute accent (e.g., CapsLock+a => á) and to ***always*** turn a following "n" into "n" with a tilde (i.e., CapsLock+n=>ñ) ?  In other words, just two keystrokes: (1) CapsLock; (2) the vowel or letter "n"?  The version in this answer requires three keystrokes.

Comment: Cheers @HippoMan ... untested, I don't want to mess w/ my PC.  You should be able to define Caps_Lock as a compose key `setxkbmap -option compose:caps` , and create a ~/.XCompose file with e.g. the following lines: `include "%L"` and `<Multi_key> <a> : "á"` and so forth ...

Comment: Thank you very much! ... but sadly, that doesn't work for me. I'm continuing to investigate.

Comment: I'm sorry man :(

Comment: No apology necessary! I very much appreciate your help!!! I posted a follow-up question here, to address this issue ... 
https://superuser.com/questions/1738088/setxkbmap-and-xcompose-unable-to-set-up-valid-dead-key

Comment: ... and I figured out how to do this! See the "Answer" i posted in the article that I mentioned immediately above in order to see what I did to accomplish this.